# d3 zoom NaN in Firefox

Tags: javascript, d3.js, firefox

I have an app using d3 zoom that works in Chrome but not (for me) in Firefox. I've boiled the zoom issue down to the following very simple example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/d3-zoom-error-in-firefox-mzid3

```
import { zoom } from "d3-zoom";
import { select } from "d3";

select("svg").call(
  zoom().on("zoom", (event) => {
    console.log(`Transform: ${event.transform.toString()}`);

    select("g").attr("transform", event.transform.toString());
  })
);
```

Wheel zooming on the gray square works for me in Firefox in Code Sandbox's default split view, but when I open the browser preview in a new tab and try it, the console logs transform values of "translate(NaN,NaN) scale(NaN)". I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: what Firefox version do you try? It works for me even in a new tab for 94.0.1 (64-bit)

Comment: @Georgy Thanks for testing! Right, important information. 94.0.1 as well. Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was caused by an extension I had installed: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/logitechsmoothscrolling/. Georgy's note that the demo worked for them caused me to look more closely at my particular Firefox profile. As that extension is 4 years old, and scrolling seems pretty smooth without it, I'm satisfied with removing the extension.